# how to handle sessions in Servlets ,

Tags: session, memory-leaks, database-connection, connection-pooling

I use servlets in my application,
To send results to jsps i used models setting them to session and access them  in jsp,and removed them from session in the end of the jsp page(using session.removeattribute("bean");),

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I made sure i always close connections in finally block ,but i keep getting Too Many Connections Error.

Comment: please advice am i using the right way to handle sessions,or is this the reason for the too many connections error